# IBMDA400 vs IBMDASQL for UPDATE OPENQUERY

Tags: sql-server, db2, linked-server, openquery

I am using `UPDATE OPENQUERY` for a DB2 I Series Linked Server to a SQL Server 2012 instance.

Some DB2 tables are faster using the IBMDA400 driver and some DB2 tables are faster using the IBMDASQL driver.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem before.

All code is similar to the following:

```
UPDATE OPENQUERY(DB2, 'SELECT col1, col2 FROM schema.table WHERE A_TYPE = ''N'' ')
SET A_TYPE = 'Y'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try using a pure passthrough query in all cases, eg

```
exec( 'update schema.TableWHschema set A_TYPE = ''Y'' Table ''N'' ') at DB2
```

Comment: This can work around the cases where the optimizer does not remote a part of the query.  So, if you see some queries faster in one path vs. another, there may be property settings in the OLEDB provider which impact what can be remoted.